How to encode RGBA and preserve alpha channel with Android MediaCodec?
I would like to encode RGBA images into webm file on Android, preserving alpha channel. I have read the answers to this question and tried following the example of https://github.com/google/grafika, unfortunately alpha channel is not preserved.
Does anyone know how to handle it properly on Android?

Please include the relevant code parts into your a section that you have developed so far.

This requires a video encoder (VP8 / AV1) that supports one of the color formats with an alpha channel (YUVA or RGBA). Unfortunately, at this point in time, they are not widely available on existing devices.
